# Returning multiple values using pointers in a function

Tags: c++, integer, boolean, implicit-conversion

Can anyone help me to understand how to return multiple values using pointers in a function? I am confused with the following example.

1. Can we assign other values to int value besides 0 or 1, while the program can still run normally?
2. What does defining the value of 0 and 1 in the if statement and else statement do for us in the int factor function?
3. What does if(!error) statement do in the main ()?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int factor(int n, int *p_addition, int *p_subtraction, int *p_squared, int *p_cubed)
{
    int value = 0;
    if (n >= 0 && n <= 100)
    {
        *p_addition = n + n;
        *p_subtraction = n - n;
        *p_squared = n*n;
        *p_cubed = n*n*n;
        value = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        value = 1;
    }
    // This function will return a value of 0 or 1
    return value;
}

int main()
{
    int number, num_add, num_sub, squared, cubed;
    int error;

    cout << "Enter a number between 0 and 100: ";
    cin >> number;

    error = factor(number, &num_add, &num_sub, &squared, &cubed);

    if (!error)
    {   
        cout << "number: " << number << endl;
        cout << "num_add: " << num_add << endl;
        cout << "num_sub: " << num_sub << endl;     
        cout << "squared: " << squared << endl;
        cout << "cubed: " << cubed << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error encountered!!" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list I think that your questions are better addressed by a tutorial. SO doesn't aim at teaching a language from scratch. Also, perhaps take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @TedKleinBergman All questions seem to be more or less related to int->bool implicit conversion, so I think it to be ok to keep it together

Answer (score 0):

1. `int` is at least 16 bits (depending on the system - hardware, operating system, 32-bit computing / vs. 64-bit computing), for numeric range, cf: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types (at least -32768 to 32767 for 16 bit integers).
2. `factor` contains `return value`, which (here) signifies to the caller, whether an error occurred. It has no other effect within `factor`.
3. The `!` negates the boolean value, so that the test is for false. `if` with an `int` implicitly converts to `bool` and tests for `error` being `0`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Boolean_conversions *The value zero (for integral [...]) [...] become[s] false. All other values become true.*

So any value beside `0` would have the same effect instead as `1`.

It would have been better to name `value` something like `wrong_input_range`.

It would have been better to make `value` a `bool` type instead of `int` and make the return type of `factor` `bool`, too.

Whether your `main` returns a value beside `0` in case of the error, you can decide by yourself. Within a script, the returned value of called programs often is tested to know, whether the script can continue.